# Full privileged console for firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

I'd like to play around with developing firefox addons, and I'm going to be accessing stuff like `Components.utils` and other objects, which are not accessible from the client code.

I've tried native web console and firebug console, and both give me an error when I'm trying to access `utils` object.

Is there firefox javascript console, which would give me full access to all firefox objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use devtools:Scratchpad (*shift F4*; it's built into Firefox and is accessible under the web development menu).  You'll need to set the pref `devtools.chrome.enabled` to `true` in *about:config*, and set scratchpad environment to *browser* from Scratchpad's menu.  Once you've done that, whatever code you run in scratchpad can access chrome objects and operates with chrome privileges.

No addons or separate applications are necessary.

Comment: [Scratchpad is apparently going away in Firefox 71](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Deprecated_tools#Scratchpad).

Answer (score 2):

Try [MozRepl](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/mozrepl/).

I'm using it with `rlwrap telnet localhost ...`.

Comment: by the way - in the new version you can't specify the connection port (there are no "settings" that I can see). would you know what that port would be?

Comment: Default port is 4242. You can change the port in `Tool > MozRepl > Change port` menu.

Comment: BTW, I'm using Firefox 21.0, MozRepl 1.1.2.